# IDA Pro script to resolve indirect API calls?

Tags: ida

Often, especially when dealing with malware files, you'll end up in a situation where all the APIs are dynamically resolved at runtime inside a given buffer, this approach considerably slow down the reversing process (and makes the decompiler useless: (DWORD *)dword_123456(INT, UINT)()) because the analyst has to run the malware, resolve the api and by hand put a comment next to each api call. I've found the indirectcalls plugin, but it seems to work only with "standard" C++ methods. Is there any script, or funcionality I don't know about, that's able to patch the executable, even during the debugging, in order to call the APIs with their real names?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/deresz/funcap - one of the functionalities it provides is I think what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script called `renimp.idc` that is shipped with IDA in the `idc` folder of IDA's installation directory. Just attach IDA at runtime (in cases of malware analysis you will probably better want to use a remote debugger), navigate to the API address table created by the unpacker and select all entries. Then run the said script. It will rename all pointers to the correct API it points to, so IDA's type-library is able to resolve the correct typedefs for it from it's internal database again.